# How to do button action in ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I am new to ASP. I need to insert values into database using ASP on clicking on submit button.
How to do that I do know.

My Code Is:

```
      <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
      <!--#include file="connection.asp"-->
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <title>Form</title>

      </head>
      <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
      <h3>FORM</h3>
      <table align="center" cellpadding = "10">
      <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Mobile Number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="umobile" id="umobile" maxlength="10" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Email Address</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="uemail" id="uemail" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
      <td>Residing City
      <td><input type="text" name="rescity" id="rescity" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </td>
      </tr>

      </table>
      </form>
      <body>
      <%

      uname = request.Form("uname")
      umobile = request.Form("umobile")
      uemail = request.Form("uemail")
      city = request.Form("city")

      set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
      Qry = "INSERT INTO enquirydetails([name],[mobile],[email],[residingcity]) values ('"&(uname)&"','"&(umobile)&"','"&(uemail)&"','"&(city)&"')"
       rs.OPEN Qry,Conn

       %>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Using this code if I go to that page the values getting inserted as blank.

Please give me any Suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand the parentheses around the variables in your sql--'"&(uname)&"'   Those should come out.  There are some insert examples here you can follow as well--http://www.codefixer.com/codesnippets/insert_date_access_sql.asp

Comment: Your missing a check to see if your form has been posted something like `If Len(Request.Form) > 0 Then` around your parameters and insert code. Otherwise even when you have not posted any data the insert will still fire.

Comment: @Dee Seriously recommending links that promote bad practice? How do you even know the OP is using MS Access?

Comment: Well that doesn't take a genius does it, last activity 11 minutes ago down-vote on my answer 11 minutes ago. Really childish @Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no check to see whether the data in your form has been submitted the code to insert a new record is running whenever the page is loaded.

Usually the way to approach this is check the length `Request.Form` to see if any form parameters have been submitted. Something like this should fix your code;

```vb
<%
If Len(Request.Form) > 0 Then
  uname = request.Form("uname")
  umobile = request.Form("umobile")
  uemail = request.Form("uemail")
  city = request.Form("city")

  set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Qry = "INSERT INTO enquirydetails([name],[mobile],[email],[residingcity]) values ('"&(uname)&"','"&(umobile)&"','"&(uemail)&"','"&(city)&"')"
  rs.OPEN Qry,Conn
End If
%>
```

There is still a problem however and that is with the approach to the `INSERT`. By dynamically assigning values directly to the SQL string you are leaving the application open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is a common attack aimed at web applications with unsecured calls to a database back-end.

ADO provides a useful object called `ADODB.Command` which helps us with this by building parametrised queries, here is an example of how to replace your existing code;

```vb
<%
Dim cmd, sql

If Len(Request.Form) > 0 Then
  uname = request.Form("uname")
  umobile = request.Form("umobile")
  uemail = request.Form("uemail")
  city = request.Form("city")

  Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  sql = "INSERT INTO enquirydetails([name],[mobile],[email],[residingcity]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
  With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = Conn 'Assuming this is your connection string
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = sql
    'Create Parameters and append them in order
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@mobile", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@email", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@residingcity", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255))
    'Assign values to the parameters
    .Parameters("@name").Value = uname
    .Parameters("@mobile").Value = umobile
    .Parameters("@email").Value = uemail
    .Parameters("@residingcity").Value = city
    .Execute()
  End With
  Set cmd = Nothing
End If
%>
```

> **NOTE:** If you have problems with this code it is likely the use of Named Constants (`adCmdText` etc) to fix this see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) which describes how to use Named Constants.

Comment: Thank you it is working fine,but how to give button name in this.@Lankymart

Comment: @Janani Any `<input>` tag will be picked up the `Request.Form` collection if the following is true. **1.** `<input>` is a child of the `<form>` being submitted. **2.** `<input>` has a `name` attribute, without a `name` it will not be submitted and this is how it is recognised in the `Request.Form` collection. If you want the value of your submit button to be passed change your `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="submit" name="yourname" value="Submit" />` then you can retrieve it using `Request.Form("Submit")`.

Comment: Down-vote seriously? Do you want to explain what is wrong with the answer please?

Comment: Sorry typo in my last example should have been `Request.Form("yourname")` because `Request.Form` goes off your `name` attribute from your `<input>`.

Comment: Please give me some example program for Download Excel in ASP. - Lankymart

Comment: Hi @Janani that would be a new question, but I think you'll find there are few of that specific question already on SO.